# Distance from a point to a curve that is the square root of a quadratic equation.

Tags: calculus, geometry

I have an an equation for a curve that is $$y(x)=\sqrt{(Ax^2+Bx+C)}$$  I am trying to find the equation for the distance from any point (px, py) to the curve.  I understand the theory of the distance formula $$d(x)=\sqrt{(x-px)^2 + (\sqrt{(Ax^2+Bx+C)}-py)^2} $$and the shortest distance being perpendicular to the tangent as described in this link:
[Shortest distance between parabola and point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2815493/shortest-distance-between-parabola-and-point) and a few others.  I understand taking the derivative of the distance and finding where that is equal to zero.  This is all fairly basic Algebra/Calculus.  The problem comes in when taking the derivative with the chain rule and setting the numerator equal to zero.  It ends up being a fourth order polynomial with some extensive coefficients.  How can I find the roots of this polynomial or at least estimate something?

If I use desmos graphing calculator and plot the curve and even the derivavtive that I derived along with the desmos d/dx, everything lines up and desmos easily identifies a minimum in the distance function and the location where the derivative crosses the x axis as the zero.  The points pop up correctly.  Desmos finds the correct answer without any lag so the computation it is doing must not be too strenuous.  I have plenty of horsepower for compute if required for some type of recursive searching or something like that.

What is the best way to attack this problem from either straight math on the polynomial or some type of computational brute force method?

Comment: $d(x)$ is non-negative, so its minimum is the same as the minimum of $d^2(x)$ which has one less square root to worry about.

Comment: Thank you for looking at it, however the numerator of the derivative is actually the same as $d^2(x)$, so I am still in the same boat.

Comment: The final equation is a quartic, and you cannot change that. To make the calculations somewhat easier, you could first translate the $\,x\,$ axis so that $\,B=0\,$ under the radical.

Comment: @ryang, yes and repaired.  I spent too much time with the introduction to Mathjax and trying to make it look nice that I did not make sure the equation was correct.